# Swiper js duplicated slides

Tags: swiper.js

I am facing an issue in swiper js. When it has only 2 slides it duplicates the slides one more time. I don't need loop and when it is 3 and less than 3 i don't need navigation too. I have tried loopDestroy() function, but when i use this it displays blank space after last slide. Here's the code.

```
var swiperproject = new Swiper(".project-details-swiper", {
    navigation: {
      nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
      prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
    },
    slidesPerView: 3,
    spaceBetween: 30,
    slidesPerGroup: 1,
    //loop: true,
    loopFillGroupWithBlank: true,
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

`loop` by is nature **"duplicate"** slides.
You can add your own logic and pass loop true/false related to this logic.

```
let loop_slider = true;
let num_of_slides = 4;

let num_of_slides_before_init = document.querySelectorAll(".swiper-slide").length;

if(num_of_slides_before_init < num_of_slides){
  loop_slider = false;
}
```

Snippet example:

```js
let loop_slider = true;
const num_of_slides = 4;
let swiper_sliders = document.querySelectorAll(".swiper");

// forEach method, could be shipped as part of an Object Literal/Module
// for class
for (const this_slider of swiper_sliders){
  //work as per usual
  let num_of_slides_before_init = this_slider.querySelectorAll(".swiper-slide").length;
  if(num_of_slides_before_init < num_of_slides){
    loop_slider = false;
  }

  var swiper = new Swiper(this_slider, {
    slidesPerView: 3,
    loop: loop_slider,
    spaceBetween: 30,
    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
      clickable: true,
    },
  });

};
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;

  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

[scroll]{
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8.4.5/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h1>Loop true (Dynamic)</h1>
<div class="swiper mySwiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>    
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
<br><br>
<h1>Loop false (Dynamic)</h1>
<div class="swiper mySwiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```